# How do I use the Get-MgReportTeamUserActivityUserDetail Graph Powershell command?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to work out how I can automate some Teams activity reports using the Get-MgReportTeamUserActivityUserDetail PowerShell Graph SDK cmdlet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.reports/get-mgreportteamuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-powershell-1.0

I'm stumped on a couple of things

1. When I just try to run it locally to validate it works I get errors with the -OutFile parameter. I was (probably naively) assuming I'd just need to provide a local file path to where I wanted the report saved to? When I run it, I get an error that the filepath cannot be found. I assumed it would create it for me as part of the process? I did try creating a blank file with the same name but got the same error

How should I be using the -OutFile parameter?

The basic command I'm running is this (creds left blank intentionally....)

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Reports

$Cert = "xxx"
$ClientID = "xxx"
$TenantID = "xxx"

Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $ClientID -TenantID $TenantID -CertificateThumbprint $Cert

Get-MgReportTeamUserActivityUserDetail -Period "D7" -Outfile "c:\users\x\documents\x.csv"
```

Thoughts?

I'd then want to get this into an automation runbook to grab the report on a set basis but am getting stuck well before that!? :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran a similar command and it worked as expected.

The command expects you to pass the path that already exists and not the file, the file name you specify here would be automatically created. if the file already exists then it will override.

Lastly, make sure the environment you are running has the appropriate permissions like read and write the directory in which you are trying to save the file

Get-MgReportTeamUserActivityUserDetail -Period "D7" -Outfile "C:\Users\myname\Documents\testx.csv"